# LessCSS/JS compiler and compressor for Java project

Tags: java, compression, minify, less

I am looking for a Java tool to add compilation and compression of static files (css (less),js) into my build process.

The only tool that I found is [wr04j](http://alexo.github.com/wro4j/). However, since I don't use Maven I need to find an alternative.

My requirements are the following:

- compilation of .less css files
- to be able to combine css and js files
- versioning
- compress js and minify css
- easy integration with a build process (development vs. production)

Comment: Does it need to be java because these components are all generated dynamically?

Comment: No it doesn't. However, since it's a Java project I think it will be better if it can be integrated with the build.

Comment: what are you using for your build?

Answer (score 2):

Asual has a less compiler for java: http://www.asual.com/lesscss/

The google closure compile also is a java js compressor: http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

However, if you know statically what these files look like you an use a js framework to package the js and less files.  One I'm pretty familiar with is javascriptmvc.  It can take a tree of js and/or less and smash it all into a single js and css file for deployment: http://javascriptmvc.com/